# Swift make Generic function from JSON request

Tags: json, swift, function, generics, request

I'm using JSONRPCKit lib, so there's final request contains that Request

```
let request1 = RPCRequest(params: SomeParams)
let batch1 = batchFactory.create(request1)
let httpRequest1 = MyServiceRequest(batch: batch1)
Session.send(httpRequest1){ result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let auth):
        let gson = JSON(auth)
        print(gson)
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error: ", error)
    }
}
```

I have to make a lot of requests like this. So i want to make it Generic to keep reuse it not typing everything again.

Could you please help me?

Comment: What kind of requests? How the other  types of requests look like? What's the common denominator for those?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a generic method which wraps these code inside something like this,

```
func sendRequest<T>(request: RCPRequest,
                    mapping: @escaping (JSON) throws -> T,
                    completion: @escaping  (T?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let batch = batchFactory.create(request)
    let httpRequest = MyServiceRequest(batch: batch)

    Session.send(httpRequest){ result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let auth):
            let gson = JSON(auth)
            do {
                let output = try mapping(gson)
                completion(output, nil)
            } catch {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like this,

```
let request1 = RPCRequest(params: SomeParams)
sendRequest(request: request1,
            mapping: { json in
                    // convert from json to the custom type T, whatever T is
                    // throw error if something isnt right in json
            },
            completion: { output, error in
                if let output = output {

                }
            })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! I didn't understand some aspects. When I'm doing mapping: "json in" what custom type "T" should convert JSON. Could you please give simple example of scenario